# How to know the number of input splits for a mapper in mapreduce program?

Tags: hadoop

Is there any way that we can know number of input splits before adding them to the output collector in `mapreduce` program

I tried with below code

```
opCol.collect(new Text(Integer.toString(total)), new IntWritable(
                Count))
```

Any help would appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you check the [FileInputFormat](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/2.6.0/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/input/FileInputFormat.java#FileInputFormat.getSplits%28org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobContext%29) class's getSplits method, it sets the number of split as `job.getConfiguration().setLong(NUM_INPUT_FILES, files.size());`

So from your mapper using `int splitCount = context.getConfiguration().get("mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.numinputfiles");`